# Есть ли разница между своим значением поля serialVersionUID и тем, который генерирует jdk?

Tags: java, сериализация, io, десериализация

Среда разработки всегда предлагает гигантские значения поля  `serialVersionUID`. Но в интернете я прочитал, что полю можно дать любое значение, например 1:

```java
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Есть ли разница между своим значением `serialVersionUID` и тем, который генерирует `IDE`? И если разницы нет, то зачем такие громадные значения?

**P.S.** Я знаю, 1 и громадные значения занимают одинаковое место в памяти. Меня интересует лишь, в чём смысл громадных значений, если всегда можно написать 1. В `jdk` есть даже специальная утилита для генерации `serialVersionUID`!

Comment: Разницы никакой, смысл в самом существовании этого поля. А вот "гигантские" значения, генерируемые IDE, и написанное Вами 1L занимают в памяти абсолютно одинаково места. Почитайте про типы.

Comment: @Adm123 Про то, что 1L и 1234567890L занимают одинаковое место, я знаю, но все эти огромные значения усложняют код в плане читаемости.  Вот я и спрашиваю, зачем же они нужны?

Comment: Генератор - генерирует ) Согласитесь, было бы странно, если бы генератор long-значений отдавал только числа в пределах от 0 до 9. Только в этом и "смысл".

Comment: @Adm123 если можно было бы использовать значения от 1 до 9, то генератора бы не было =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Генератор высчитывает `serialVersionUID` на основе содержимого класса (по сути хеш-сумму из сигнатур класса и полей, всего что участвует в сериализации) - это гарантирует (в высокой степени вероятности) уникальный `serialVersionUID` для уникальной структуры класса.
Если вы ставите своё число, то должны осознавать какие изменения класса критичны для (де)сериализации и менять `serialVersionUID` после таких изменений.

Answer (score 2):

Да, есть разница. `serialVersionUID` является уникальным идентификатором, который используется для верификации сериализованного класса. Если вы задаете свое значение для `serialVersionUID`, то это значение должно соответствовать текущей версии класса. Если вы используете значение, генерируемое JDK, то оно автоматически обновляется при изменении класса. В этом случае рекомендуется использовать значение, генерируемое JDK, чтобы избежать несовместимости между сериализованным классом и десериализованным классом.

Нет разницы между своим значением `serialVersionUID` и тем, который генерирует JDK или IDE, но указание своего значения может дать вам больше контроля над версией класса.

Уже ответили, что в Java serialVersionUID - это уникальный идентификатор класса, который используется при сериализации и десериализации. Если хотите управлять версией класса, укажете свое значение serialVersionUID.

serialVersionUID значение, сгенерированное JDK/IDE, является длинным целым числом, что обеспечивает уникальность для каждого класса. Такое большое значение необходимо, чтобы избежать коллизий, когда вы работаете с множеством классов.